# Automated reboot without root

Tags: reboot, automation, automate

I'm responsible for an automation lab with many Android phones connected to Linux servers via adb for testing. We have an issue where devices will sometimes disappear from adb which means that someone has to manually find the phone and reboot it before it will come back. I'm interested in finding solutions to reduce this need for manual intervention.

One idea I had was that we could periodically send a ping to the device from the host and if the device did not receive a ping in a specific period it would assume it was disconnected and reboot itself. The issue is that we cannot root these phones so I'm not sure if that is possible.

I do however, have the ability to write and install my own apps on the devices and I don't need to worry about any playstore rules.  Is there anyway I can achieve this without rooting the device?

Comment: For rebooting the device the process calling it requires root permissions. The only way to reboot a device without using the UI is via adb. Therefore as long as the devices are not rooted this will, not work.

Comment: scheduled reboot is possible with automate apps like automate, macrodroid, tasker. if that devices have wifi or sim card you could even use message received as trigger for /system/bin/reboot

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/tasker-5-9-2-beta-run-adb-shell-commands-without-tethered-pc